# How to use variable as array key in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, foreach

I have this json

```
var jsonobj = {'fieldname1':'test1','fieldname2':'test2'};
```

and I want to make the same process in Javascript or jQuery for say both jsonobj element...

I have tried

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonobj);
var fieldList = ['fieldname1','fieldname2'];
$.each( fieldList , function( i, field ) {
alert(obj.field);
});
```

waiting for an answer like alert('test1') then alert('test2') but not working... any idea if this is possible in a way or in another? I have also tried with obj.{field}, obj.[field] but no way, doesn't work! ^^'

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets to get the named property.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonobj);
var fieldList = ['fieldname1','fieldname2'];
$.each( fieldList , function( i, field ) {
    alert(obj[field]);
});
```

Comment: pfffff... thanks much! Just realized the "." problem... sometimes easy stuff is the hardest to realize.. ^^'